# Angle vector in polar system represented by Cartesian vector

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, polar-coordinates

$x=r\cos\theta,\,y=r\sin\theta\implies r^2=x^2+y^2,\,\theta=\arctan(y/x)$

I can show that $\hat{r}=\cos\theta\hat i+\sin\theta\hat j$, where the `hat` vectors are unit, and $\hat i,\,\hat j$ are in $x,y$ directions respectively.

I can show that $\hat\theta=-\sin\theta\hat i+\cos\theta\hat j$ in geometry using the tangent chord angle theorem.

Can anyone provide an algebraic proof for the $\hat\theta$ equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unit vector $\hat \theta$ is defined as the unit vector that is normal to the position vector $\vec r$ and points in the direction of increasing $\theta$.

Write $\hat \theta = \cos(\alpha)\hat x+\sin(\alpha)\hat y$ for some angle $\alpha$.  Then, we have

$$\hat \theta \cdot \hat r=\cos(\theta-\alpha)=0\implies \alpha = \theta\pm \pi/2\tag 1$$

The ambiguity of the sign in $(1)$ is resolved when enforcing that $\hat \theta$ points in the direction of increasing $\theta$, in which case we have $\alpha = \theta +\pi/2$ and therefore

$$\hat \theta = -\sin(\theta)\hat x+\cos(\theta)\hat y$$

Alternatively, we note that

$$\begin{align}
0&=\frac{d(1)}{d\theta}\\\\
&=\frac{d(\hat r\cdot \hat r)}{d\theta}\\\\
&=2\hat r\cdot \frac{d\hat r }{d\theta}\\\\
&=2\hat r\cdot (-\sin(\theta)\hat x+\cos(\theta)\hat y)
\end{align}$$

So, $\hat r$ is orthogonal to the unit vector $-\sin(\theta)\hat x+\cos(\theta)\hat y$, which points in the direction of increasing $\theta$.

Comment: Is my understanding correct? $\frac{d(\hat r\cdot\hat r)}{d\theta}=\frac{d(\hat r\cdot\hat r)}{d\hat r}\frac{d\hat r}{d\theta}=2\hat r\frac{d\hat r}{d\theta}$. $2$ is canceled since the equation equals to zero.

Comment: Sorry for not accepting your answer yet. Just a quick question: did you cancel the coefficient `2` implicitly since it's a formula equal to zero, as I asked in the first comment?

Comment: Good catch!  There was a typo (ommitted $2$).  The answer has now been edited.

Answer (score 0):

Simple. $\hat{\theta}$ is orthogonal to $\hat{r}$ and on the *xy*-plane (or orthogonal to $\hat{k}$). You do that with the $\times$ vector cross product operator.

$$\hat{\theta} = \hat{k} \times \hat{r} $$